# jaxb: inline elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Given:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
class Foo {
   public Bar getBar() {...}
}

class Bar {
   @XmlElement(name = "string")
   public String getString() {return "hello";}
}
```

How do I annotate so the XML will be:

```
<foo>
   <string>hello</string>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following leveraging the `@XmlValue` annotation.

**Foo**

```
@XmlRootElement
class Foo {
    @XmlElement(name="string")
    public Bar getBar() {...}
}
```

**Bar**

```
class Bar {
    @XmlValue
    public String getString() {return "hello";}
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Comment: The way the question has been stated, this answer is technically correct, and it should be accepted, even though I guess it is not what the OP wanted. I suppose the OP's main concern is mainly the elimination of the <bar>...</bar> tags, and not so much the rendering of the string as XML content. He probably has in mind (as I do) a "Bar" object which contains a lot more stuff besides just a string, and he wants all that stuff to appear as immediate children of "Foo" without the "Bar" tags.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use [@XmlSeeAlso](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) annotation on top of your class.

You can use @XmlSeeAlso annotation when you want another Entity bean to be included in the XML output. Can you try this in your Foo class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
@XmlSeeAlso(Bar.class)
class Foo {
   public Bar getBar() {...}
}
```

**Update1:**

For your comment to remove the bar tag in the XML try using [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)'s](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php). @XmlPath will solve your issue.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
@XmlSeeAlso(Bar.class)
class Foo {
   @XmlPath(".")
   public Bar getBar() {...}
}
```

Refer [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html) for more details.

Comment: Wouldn't this still result in <foo><bar><string>hello</string></bar></foo>?

Comment: +1 - You could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension for this use case, but check out my answer for how this could be done using just the standard JAXB annotations:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14052993/383861.  The `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation is not required for this use case.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you can to eliminate the tag **bar** from resulting XML:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148576